# R shiny DT hover shows detailed table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to work on an R shiny app where I want to show a consolidated table on top and when the user hovers on any line item it would show the detailed section of that table.So here's the code for the first table

```
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),

  # Create a new row for the table.
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- mpg

  data <-data %>% group_by(manufacturer,year) %>% 
    summarise(cty = round(mean(cty),2),hwy = round(2,mean(hwy)))

  # Filter data based on selections
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({


    data
  }))

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

[image]

Now when the user hovers on `Audi` for example it should show a detailed version just for`Audi` something like this in a table below.Can this be done in shiny with DT on hover or click.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way. If you prefer to display the child table on click rather than on hover, replace `"table.on('mouseover', 'td', function(){"` with `"table.on('click', 'td', function(){"`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")

callback <- c(
  "table.on('mouseover', 'td', function(){",
  "  var index = table.cell(this).index();",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('cell', index, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  dat <- mpg

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  })

  filteredData <- eventReactive(input[["cell"]], {
    i <- input[["cell"]]$row + 1
    j <- input[["cell"]]$column
    if(j > 0){
      dat[dat[[j]] == dat[i,j], , drop = FALSE]
    }else{
      NULL
    }
  })

  output[["tblfiltered"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      filteredData(),
      fillContainer = TRUE, 
      options = list(
        pageLength = 5
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(filteredData(), {
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        DTOutput("tblfiltered"), 
        size = "l", 
        easyClose = TRUE
      )
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get this error : `Warning: Error in : `i` must have one dimension, not 2.
  [No stack trace available]`

Comment: @SNT This code works for me. Did you get this error with another dataset ?

Comment: No c the same dataset