# R shiny DT hover how to report NULL when mouse is moved off the table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

Related to [R shiny DT hover shows detailed table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310063/r-shiny-dt-hover-shows-detailed-table/74828432#74828432)

I've been working on an application where I would like to display some text as a user mouses over a table.

I've been working with a modified version of the example from the above link, but there's one hang-up.

Is there a way to have `input[["cell"]]` revert to `NULL` in the case where the user moves the mouse outside the table? With the current implementation it reports the last value the mouse touched before departure.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")

callback <- c(
  "table.on('mouseover', 'td', function(){",
  "  var index = table.cell(this).index();",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('cell', index, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("tbl"),
  htmlOutput("msg")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  dat <- mpg

  output[["tbl"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      dat,
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  })

  output[["tblfiltered"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      filteredData(),
      fillContainer = TRUE,
      options = list(
        pageLength = 5
      )
    )
  })

  output$msg <- renderText(paste(input[["cell"]], collapse = ","))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `mouseout` event I think. Attached to the table body.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent) for the help

Amended the `callback` as follows

```
callback <- c(
  "table.on('mouseover', 'td', function(){",
  "  var index = table.cell(this).index();",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('cell', index, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});,
  table.on('mouseout', 'td', function(){",
  "  Shiny.setInputValue('cell', null, {priority: 'event'});",
  "});
"
)
```